# The restriction of representation of $A\otimes_{\alpha} B$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $||.||_{\alpha}$ be a C*-norm on $A\odot B$, $A\otimes_{\alpha} B$ be the completion and $\xi$ be a state on $A\otimes_{\alpha} B$. Let ($\pi_{\xi}, H_{\xi}, v_{\xi}$) be the GNS triplet and $\pi_{\xi, A}$ and $\pi_{\xi, B}$ be the *restriction* homomorphisms on $A$ and $B$ respectively.

My question is: **How to verify $\pi_{\xi}(A\otimes_{\alpha} B)$ is contained in the $C^{*}$-algebra generated by $\pi_{\xi, A}$ and $\pi_{\xi, B}$ ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
\pi_\xi(a\otimes b)\left(\sum c_j\otimes d_j\right)v_\xi=\left(\sum ac_j\otimes bd_j\right)v_\xi=\pi_{\xi,A}(a)\left(\sum c_j\otimes bd_j\right)v_\xi
=\pi_{\xi,A}(a)\pi_{\xi,B}(b)\left(\sum c_j\otimes d_j\right)v_\xi.
$$
Then
$$
\pi_\xi(\sum a_j\otimes b_j)=\sum \pi_{\xi,A}(a_j)\pi_{\xi,B}(b_j)\in C^*(\pi_{\xi\,A}(A),\pi_{\xi,B}(B)).
$$
By continuity, $\pi_\xi(A\otimes_\alpha B)\subset C^*(\pi_{\xi\,A}(A),\pi_{\xi,B}(B)).$

Comment: Since the $^{*}$-homomorphism between two C*-algebra is norm decreasing, then the $\pi_{\xi}$ is continuous, right?

Comment: Yes, any C$^*$-algebra homeomorphism is contractive; in particular,  continuous.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I don't understand why you are acting $\pi_{\xi}(a \otimes b)$ on $(\sum c_j \otimes d_j)v_{\xi}$?? I understand that $v_{\xi}$ is in $H_{\xi}$. Why $(\sum c_j \otimes d_j)v_{\xi}$ though?

Comment: $v_\xi$ is a single fixed (cyclic) vector.To form a dense subset of $H_\xi$, as per the GNS representation, you need $(A\odot B)v_\xi$.